# Where does the trigger.io forge.logging.log (etc) output go when running on the real device (IOS or Android)?

Tags: trigger.io

Where does the trigger.io forge.logging.log (etc) output go when running on the real device (IOS or Android)?

Example,

```
forge.logging.log('inside my app');
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, the log output is visible in the XCode organiser: click on Console under your device on the left sidebar.

For Android, if you started the app on the device using `forge run android` the output is piped into your terminal. If you didn't start the app from our tooling, the log output is still available: run `adb logcat` in a terminal.

In both cases, make sure you have your logging module [configured properly](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/logging.html#config). If you have the level set to `ERROR`, debug level messages will not appear!

Comment: What is the recommended configuration setting for production/app store?

Comment: Logging does incur some performance overhead, but it's marginal until you start doing huge amounts of it. To keep things simple, I'd recommend logging everything: if you're doing several log statements every second, that's probably the point to think about scaling it back.